# Why would a Split-plot ANOVA test provide less statitical evidence of an interaction term than MANOVA

Tags: manova

Running both a Split-plot ANOVA and a MANOVA on a repeated measure analysis data set and while both methods provide statically significant results the F values are really different. I would have thought they would be closer together.

Comment: What are you considering "really different?"  Remember the F-distribution has a long tail. Are the probabilities really different or the F value?

Comment: They aren't "that different."  Rather the MANOVA method provides (or appears to) provide more (higher) statistical evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In split-plot designs you are usually assuming a correlation and in classic MANOVA the assumption is independence between groups.  If you work through the various sum of squares and use the right denominators MANOVA can give larger F. I do not believe this is is necessarily  the case. However, generally the assumption of independence will result in smaller sum of square errors and a larger F value.